# can't assign the global dictionary parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, reference, pickle

I've tried to load datafile in pickle object, but when it load, it assigned to the new parameter, the reference memory is different and I couldn't find the way to assign it to global dictionary parameter

module.py

```py
import pickle
path2file='c:\file'
Objects={}


def loadPickle():
  global Objects
  print(id(Objects))  #xxx111
  with open (path2file, 'rb') as fp:
    Objects = pickle.load(fp)
 print(id(Objects)) #xxx222
 # Objects= copy.copy(x)
```

main.py

```py
from module import *

loadPickle()
print(id(Objects))  #xxx111
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to the name `Objects` a different dictionary - the one that you loaded from the pickle file.

Since the name will now *refer* to a different dictionary the `id(Objects)` will be different and corresponding to the 2nd dictionary and not the first.

Now, when you import the module the `module.Objects` is loaded once (and prior to the change in the `loadPickle`) into *global* scope.

When you change it in `loadPickle` it is changed only at the level of the module `module` and not in the global scope.

However, when you do:

```
import module
module.loadPickle()
print(id(module.Objects))
```

it should do what you want.

Another approach could be to create the global variable from within the function `loadPickle` while it does not exist in the global scope (just remove the intialization `Objects = {}` form `module`). In such a case the variable will contain the expected dictionary loaded from the pickle.

Comment: thanks but, it does not work, I use `  from module import *  ` , so the prefixes do not change anything, the problem is it will not be assigned to any global pram and automatically be assigned  to local param